# Checklist web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to rails and I am currently in the process of developing a check list app.  I would greatly appreciate some guidance as I am currently suck in my development process and would just like some help getting me on my way.

**The project I am aiming to achieve is as follows:**

User has a homepage, user can add collections to watch.  User can then toggle (have/don't have) products within that collection.  User has no privileges to edit content of the collections or projects, all the user has access too is simply saying if they have the product or not.

Users homepage will consist of a listing of all their collections, and under their collections will be the products that correlates.

**Where I am in my development:**

Currently I have a 1 to many association with, Collections -> Products. I have taken care of the CRUD for collections, as well as the associated CRUD for products. I have generated a devise user model to provide myself with an easy sign in/sign up functionality.

**My next steps?**

That's why I'm here. I would like some guidance before I dive into further development as I don't want to drift off track.  I'm not looking for specific code snippets or generators, I am basically looking for some verification that I am on the right track and perhaps some steps to help me on my way to the next bit of functionality.

If you would like to see my current code it can be found here:
https://github.com/gogogarrett/Blind-Boxd

Thanks in advance,

Garrett

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are on the right path.

I would suggest doing the following in *loosely* the following order:

- Make sure your models contain the right fields and types of fields for your app
- Setup associations and make they are working
- Go through each view and make sure the flow is correct i.e. right forms, links are displayed and data is processed correctly
- Figure out how you want each page to be laid out and what's best for usability
- Add some styling and polish

Throughout the whole process: **write tests and use the console**

Hope this helps.